# Getting specific portions of a string using RegEx

Tags: php, regex, json

I'm trying to make a json file with all my countries cities and states (called departamentos here). I never found a complete list but now I'm following the list made by Wikipedia users in this link:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Municipios_de_Colombia

I have copied and pasted all the text within a document, making a new line for each city like this:

> Yacopí es una población y municipio del departamento de Cundinamarca

Currently I am able to select the city using RegEx with this expression:

> /.+?(?= es)/

It takes everything from the beginning of the line to where it meets " es" for the first time, which is a regular convention for each of the lines in the Wikipedia page.

Now what I want to achieve is with the same line of Regex, also get the state which can be the last or last two words. Which I think it can be reached by selecting anything after " de ". But I'm stuck.

Any help would be appreciated and maybe other people around the world can start making json files out of Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for at least the cities starting with an A. I didn't test all of them though.

```
/^(.*?) es.*de (.*)$/gm
```

Play with it here. https://regex101.com/r/yJ3gK7/1 (the whitespace is from pasting from the wiki, and shouldn't really matter here.)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, works like charm. Will implement it, output json and make a gist out of it. I hope this works for other countries as well. Thank you timoh !